# Accessing response from SimpleHTTPOperator in another task

Tags: airflow

Relating to [this earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46676449/how-to-access-the-response-from-airflow-simplehttpoperator-get-request), suppose that we have an Apache Airflow DAG that comprises two tasks, first an HTTP request (i.e., SimpleHTTPOperator) and then a PythonOperator that does something with the response of the first task.

Conveniently, using the [Dog CEO API](https://dog.ceo/dog-api/) as an example, consider the following DAG:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.providers.http.operators.http import SimpleHttpOperator
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator

default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'email': ['someone@email.com'],
    'email_on_failure': True,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 0,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=1),
}
with DAG(
    'dog_api',
    default_args=default_args,
    description='Get nice dog pics',
    schedule_interval=None,
    start_date=datetime(2021, 1, 1),
    catchup=False,
    tags=['dog'],
) as dag:
    get_dog = SimpleHttpOperator(
        task_id='get_dog',
        http_conn_id='dog_api', # NOTE: set up an HTTP connection called 'dog_api' with host 'https://dog.ceo/api'
        endpoint='/breeds/image/random',
        method="GET",
        # xcom_push=True # NOTE: no such argument in 2.2.0 but sometimes suggested by older guides online
    )
    
    def xcom_check(ds, **kwargs):
        val = kwargs['ti'].xcom_pull(key='return_value', task_ids='get_dog')
        return f"xcom_check has: {kwargs['ti']} and it says: {val}"
     
    inspect_dog = PythonOperator(
        task_id='inspect_dog',
        python_callable=xcom_check,
        provide_context=True
    )
```

We'd like to access the return value of `get_dog` inside `xcom_check`. By inspecting the logs, `get_dog` populates the xcom storage nicely to something like:

[image: xcom value]

But now, this is not currently passed to the second task. This can be seen by inspecting the logs as well, which says (among other things):

```
*redacted* Returned value was: xcom_check has: <TaskInstance: dog_api.inspect_dog manual__2021-10-30T16:27:23.081539+00:00 [running]> and it says: None
```

So obviously, the task instance is "dog_api.inspect_dog" but we'd want it to be "dog_api.get_dog". How is this done? At the time of writing, the same question is asked in the comments of the previous question, upvoted, but unanswered. I also tried [adapting this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46061162) but can't figure out what I'm still doing differently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that you did not set dependency between the tasks so `inspect_dog` may run before or in parallel to `get_dog` when this happens `get_dog` will see no xcom value because `inspect_dog` didn't push it yet.

[image]

You just need to set dependency as:

```
get_dog >> inspect_dog
```

[image]

Log :

```
[2021-10-31, 07:07:21 UTC] {python.py:174} INFO - Done. Returned value was: xcom_check has: <TaskInstance: dog_api.inspect_dog manual__2021-10-31T07:05:27.721051+00:00 [running]> and it says: {"message":"https:\/\/images.dog.ceo\/breeds\/pointer-germanlonghair\/hans1.jpg","status":"success"}
```

As for your comment in the code about `xcom_push`:
The `xcom_push` parameter was used in older Airflow versions. It was replaced by `do_xcom_push` (see [source code](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/1600f1dfd767ebb0097e1455348dc13ea68e9bb5/airflow/models/baseoperator.py#L522)). Notice that the default value of this parameter is True.